# Finding joint distribution function given marginals and a copula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose I am given that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have exponential marginal distributions with parameters $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$, respectively, and I am asked to write out the joint distribution function for $(X,Y)$ given the Clayton Copula (which I asked an earlier question about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537170/showing-the-clayton-copula-is-2-increasing)):

$$C(u,v) = \left[\max \{u^{-\theta} + v^{-\theta} - 1 ,0\} \right]^{-1/\theta}$$

for $u,v \in (0,1)$ and $\theta > 0$.

Now, since $X$ has marginal distribution function $$F_{1}(x) = \begin{cases} 1-e^{-\lambda_{1}x},& \text{for}\, x \geq 0 \\ 0,& \text{for}\,x<0\end{cases}$$
and $Y$ has marginal distribution function $$F_{2}(y) = \begin{cases} 1-e^{-\lambda_{1}y},& \text{for}\, y \geq 0 \\ 0,& \text{for}\,y<0\end{cases}$$
we have that the joint distribution is given by $$F(\mathbf{x}) = F(x,y) = C(F_{1}(x), F_{2}(y)) = \begin{cases} C(1-e^{\lambda_{1}x},1-e^{\lambda_{2}y}),&\text{for}\, x,y \geq 0 \\ C(0,0),& \text{for}\,x,y<0 \\ C(0, 1-e^{-\lambda_{2}y}),& \text{for}\,x<0,\, y\geq 0 \\ C(1-e^{-\lambda_{1}x},0),&\text{for}\,x\geq 0, \, y<0 \end{cases}\\\\ =  \\ \begin{cases} \left[\max\{(1-e^{-\lambda_{1}x})^{-\theta} + (1-e^{\lambda_{2}y})^{-\theta} - 1 ,0 \} \right]^{-1/\theta}, & \text{for}\, x,y \geq 0 \\ \left[ \max \{(0)^{-\theta}+ 0^{-\theta} - 1,0 \}\right]^{-1/\theta} = \left[ \max \{-1,0\}\right]^{-1/\theta} = 0, & \text{for}\, x,y < 0 \\ \left[ \max \{ 0^{-\theta} + (1-e^{-\lambda_{2}y})^{-\theta} - 1 , 0\}\right]^{-1/\theta} = \left[ \max\left\{\left( \frac{e^{\lambda_{2}y}-1}{e^{\lambda_{2}y}}\right)^{-\theta} -1,0\right\}\right]^{-1/\theta},&\text{for}\,x<0,\,y\geq 0 \\ \left[ \max \{  (1-e^{-\lambda_{1}x})^{-\theta} + 0^{-\theta} - 1 , 0\}\right]^{-1/\theta} = \left[ \max\left\{\left( \frac{e^{\lambda_{1}x}-1}{e^{\lambda_{1}x}}\right)^{-\theta} -1,0\right\}\right]^{-1/\theta},&\text{for}\,x\geq 0,\,y< 0  \end{cases}$$

So, my question is: Do I need all of these cases? And if not/if so, is there any way to simplify them further?

Thank you.

Comment: As was stated in the answer to the other question, there is no need for the $\max$ at all.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen because really, what was confusing me the most about this problem, and hence why I asked this question in the first place, was whether I needed all $4$ cases. The fact that you reminded me I don't need the $\max$es is helpful, but it's not what I really wanted to know. Could you tell me whether I need to include all $4$ cases, and if not, why not? Thank you.

Comment: Thus I comment and do not answer. The only interesting case is $x,y>0.$ The distribution is not supported otherwise.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen is the distribution not supported when $x.y>0$ or when $F_{1}(x)>0$, $F_{2}(y)>0$, since the copula requires that its arguments both be $>0$?

Comment: These are one and the same.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I did not know that.

Comment: As mentioned above, and in the previous post you linked, you need to recall that $P(A \cap B) = 0$ if $P(A) = 0$ or $P(B) = 0$. And therefore you have the property one of the copula, which is $C(u, 0) = C(0, v) = 0$. So all the bottom $3$ cases can be dropped safely. And as reminded again, you can drop the maximum function as well when you are dealing with the case with $\theta > 0$. The maximum function is used to cater the case for $\theta \in [-1, 0)$

Comment: @BGM thanks! You could have posted that as an answer, and I would have accepted it.